# Symfony 2 no command for generating doctrine crud

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, crud

i`m trying to generate CRUD for some entities in Symfony 2, apparently the 
generate:doctrine:crud command is unavailable.

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                        
  Command "generate:doctrine:crud" is not defined.
```

also , in the list for available commands, I only get one command.

```
generate
  generate:doctrine:entities            Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
```

is there a bundle or something in the configuration missing, or what is the cause for not having this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Addition:**

The **doctrine:generate:crud** command is provided by the [SensioGeneratorBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html)

Please also make sure you have the bundle available and registered in your **app/AppKernel.php** like this:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
          // ...
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        // ...
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        // ...
    }
```

As in my example the command is also normally only available in the dev environment. Therefore ...

```
php app/console --env=prod doctrine:generate:crud
```

.. or any other configuration that uses production enviroment won't work.

Answer (score 2):

`doctrine:generate:crud` is the command you should use

You can see a list of commands using `php app/console list`